# Break out of loop if data in one array exceedes some VALUE in another Python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have two arrays, `id`, and `x`  where `id` is a unique identifier that tells us that the values in `x` belong to a specific group. What I want to do is go through the values in `x` to see if some condition is meet and if so print the corresponding `x` value.  For example

```
id = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5])
x = np.array([10,9,6,9,7,1,12,5,10,9,8,4,6,2,1])


  counter = 1
  for i in range(len(id)):
    if id[i] == counter:
        for j in range(i,len(id)):   
           if x[j] > 7:
             continue 
           else:
              print(id[i],x[j])  
              counter += 1    
              break
```

prints

```
1 6
2 7
3 5
4 4
5 6
```

Now if we instead have

```
id = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5])
x = np.array([10,9,6,9,7,1,12,11,10,9,8,4,6,2,1])
```

The output is

```
1 6
2 7
3 4
4 4
5 6
```

Which is not the output I want because `4` is not in the group that has an `id` value of `3`. So my question is how does one only have the condition `if x[j] > 7:` evaluated if the `x` values correspond to an `id` vale that represents it and  not skip over that group?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused but I'll take a stab...
could a dictionary help?

```
id = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5])
x = np.array([10,9,6,9,7,1,12,5,10,9,8,4,6,2,1])

dict = {}
for i in range(len(id)):
    if id[i] not in dict:
        dict[id[i]] = []
    dict[id[i]].append(x[i])

#you now have a dict that is keyed by your group-id and has a list of values for that group.

for group in dict:
    vals_in_group = dict[group]
    for val in vals_in_group:
        #check value? or just print
        print group, val
```

Comment: Since I have never used dictionaries before how would I integrate this into my example? Would it just be as simple as something like `if val in vals_in_group` `do something`?

Comment: where I put #check value, val is one of the elements in vals_in_group.  if you'd like to check to see if there is a certain value in a group's list, then yes, your "if val in val_in_group: " would work...in this case, you'd perhaps remove the for loop (for vals in vals_in_group) and 'val' would be a value of your choosing.

Comment: I am a little confused as to exactly what `dict[group]` is and how to integrate `dictionary` into my code. Would you mind explaining your code a bit more for me?